# Hosting docker swarm from one docker-compose but with nodes var

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm

I'm looking to be able to run swarm from same docker-compose file which uses env variables. Currently I only achieved that all nodes are replicating Leaders env. Is it possible to let each node start from its own local env var?

My docker-compose

```
version: '3.1'

networks:
  base:

services:
  test:
    container_name: ${Name}
    restart: always
    image: ubuntu:latest
    environment:
      - Name=${Name}
    command: sh -c "echo $Name && sleep 30"
    networks:
      - base
```

Answer (score 0):

use `env_file` option

https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/

```
# .env, file
Name=<your_name>
```

```
# <your_name>.env, file
TEST_ENV=stackoverflow
```

```yaml
# docker-compose.yaml, file
version: '3.1'

services:
  test:
    container_name: ${Name}
    restart: always
    image: ubuntu:latest
    env_file:
      - ${Name}.env
    command: sh -c "set | grep TEST_ENV && sleep 30"
```

```sh
docker logs <your_name>
# TEST_ENV='stackoverflow'
```

You can set env_files with different names in different containers.
for example

```yaml
# docker-compose.yaml, file
version: '3.1'

services:
  test1:
    container_name: test1
    restart: always
    image: ubuntu:latest
    env_file:
      - first.env
    command: sh -c "set | grep TEST_FIRST_ENV && sleep 30"

  test2:
    container_name: test2
    restart: always
    image: ubuntu:latest
    env_file:
      - second.env
    command: sh -c "set | grep TEST_SECOND_ENV && sleep 30"
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, this worked, but in my case its a little hard to manage all env in one file

Comment: I recommend to write a build script in the form of generating env files for each container in a `build` directory from one env file. :) good luck guy

Comment: A little misunderstood what you are proposing

Answer (score 0):

Environment variables referenced in the docker-compose.yml file are not resolved on the leader even, they are resolved on whatever jump box you are deploying too the swarm from.

If you want to reference the env vars from the host system, from the command, or entrypoint, iirc you can escape the reference to "$$Name", but this will only make the env variable available to the entrypoint or command script which are evaluated on the host, not to values like the container_name.

Given your specific use case, perhaps service creation templates are what you are looking for: They let you inject per service instance values into `hostname`, `mount` and `env`.

```sh
version: '3.8'

services:
  test:
    env:
      MY_HOSTNAME: "{{.Node.Hostname}}"
    ...
```

See [Create Service Using Templates](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/service_create/#create-services-using-templates) for the full list of supported values.

Comment: This did a trick. but I have a question still, I have inserted it as 
    environment:
      - Name={{.Node.Hostname}}
and local env worked and even if I exec into container I can print it properly, but if I run 
     command: bash -c 'echo Name=$Name && sleep infinity' 
In my compose it doesn't recognize $Name var

Comment: Im not sure of the exact syntax. But you need to probably double escape the command in teh compose as $$Name, such that docker-compose actually passes $Name to bash in the container to evaluate.

Comment: Yeah I figured it out recently, proper way:
command: bash -c 'echo Name=$$Name && sleep infinity'